# Проверка сообщений Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Есть ли такие боты которые проверяют одинаковые ли сообщение в группе от пользователя за 24 часа? Очень нужно для группы, в случае чего будут одинаковые от одного пользователя то он удаляет сообщение и по возможности пишет в лс почему удалил.

Пробовал GroupHelpBot но я так понял что он такого не умеет